# Assumptions with Bayes's Theorem

Tags: bayesian, bayes-theorem

After reading extensively on the subject I would like to clarify this apparent problem with "Bayes Rule".

Namely the notation often used P(A and B) = P (B and A) has a big assumption that I will try to point out. This might be similar to questions regarding the inverse fallacy that I have seen around but I will try to point out something that I think is more specific although likely related.

Bayes realies on the following statement:

> P (A and B) = P (B and A)

and

> 1) P (A and B) = P(A) * P(B|A)

"this assumes A happens first and **A affects B**" (i.e. the probability of A is multiplied by the probability of B once we know A has happened).

> 2) P (B and A) = P(B) * P(A|B)

"again, this calculates the combined probability but in terms of P(B) and the probability of A assuming B has happened (i.e. P(A|B), and therefore assumes **B affects A**."

This might seem logical as we use this notation because we are dealing with dependent variables. Had we been thinking these variables are independent we would say **P (A and B) = P(A) * P(B)**.

**However, my question is "What if the first assumption is correct but the second one is not?" Specifically Bayes seems to assume that if A affect B then B must affect A but this is NOT necessarily true in real life. In this case P(B and A) = P(B) * P(A) and therefore:**

> P(A and B) ≠ P (B and A)

I can think of several examples in which the order of events have an effect in on direction but not in the other.

So it seems to me that when using Bayes and assuming P(A and B) = P(B and A) we are making a big underlying assumption, in addition to the value estimates that will follow. Some people say well P(A and B) = L (B and A) , meaning that you are using that notation to refer to the fact that you are trying to estimate P(A and B) on the basis of a Likelihood function in terms of B, but then again that approximation could be terribly flawed (just like many things in statistics I suppose).

References:
http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkbayes/html/thinkbayes002.html
http://link.springer.com/article/10.3758%2FBF03195278

Comment: Where are your quotes taken from?

Comment: Conditional probabilities are not about who affects who, but rather, is about the estimate of the likeliness of occurrence of $B$ given that $A$ already happens.

Comment: "Bayes seems to assume that if A affect B then B must affect A" If "A affect(s) B" means $P(B\mid A)\ne P(B)$ then indeed "B must affect A" in the sense that $P(A\mid B)\ne P(A)$. This is a mathematical fact. If you mean something else by "A affects B", please explain what it is.

Comment: @AaronS I added one of the sources. The occurrence of B given that A already happens can have a higher probability of happening than the probability of B alone, P(B), depending on what event we are talking about. However, my problem is that the opposite might not be true and some of the properties/assumptions would not be true.

Comment: @Did it is a mathematical fact that independent variables are not affected by other variables in our model so if you compute P(B|A) AND B IS AN INDEPENDENT VARIABLE you will in fact get P(B).

Comment: No idea what you are trying to say. The phrase "not affected by other variables" is from an exotic lexicon I am unaware of. Re "INDEPENDENT VARIABLE", please 1. slow down on the caps and 2. notice that "independent" per se means nothing. If you mean that if B is independent **of A** then P(B|A)=P(B), then you are right but I wonder why you see fit to post a comment to me to say that. (No need to answer to this comment if this is to add other trivialities, thanks.)

Comment: "Specifically Bayes seems to assume that if A affect B then B must affect A but this is NOT necessarily true in real life. In this case P(B and A) = P(B) * P(A) and therefore: P(A and B) ≠ P (B and A) I can think of several examples in which the order of events have an effect in on direction but not in the other." To make people understand your question, you might want to add some examples of this startling claim.

Comment: @Did the whole idea of the post is to clarify a doubt/question regarding the assumptions when using Bayes.

Comment: Step 1: "I can think of several examples in which the order of events have an effect in on direction but not in the other." Step 2: Please show some. Step 3: Insults but no example whatsoever. What is going on?

Answer (score 5):

You're bringing causation and temporality in where they don't belong. $A\cap B$ is merely the event which occurs if both $A$ and $B$ occur. There's no implication of temporal order or cause and effect. Events are sets, and $\cap$ has the usual set-theoretic meaning here; hence it's symmetric.

Comment: thanks joriki,  the Theorem relies on dependent variables but it seems someone can have a variable (B) that depends on (A) but (A) might not depend or affect probability on (B).  Therefore P(A|B) and the probability of P(A) would be numerically the same and that creates a problem. So in essence the dependent variables have to go both ways? IT seem to me you can have 1) independent variables 2) completely interdependent variables  3) partially independent variables.

Comment: @BluePython: This concept of one variable "affecting" the other is misguided. There's no cause and effect here, only a symmetric relationship. You write "it seems" several times, but you don't explain why it seems to you like that. If you see an asymmetry, you're going to have to point it out more specifically.

Comment: So this symmetry is given by the fact that we often know or assume as "prior knowledge" P(A) , P(B), and we know how often we "see" A and B  together, P(A and B). Therefore, our conditional probabilities in this case become "strictly" defined, since we are just solving for the unknown which can be P(A|B) or P(B|A). I guess my question ends up being "more of the same" regarding the frequentist vs Bayes debate. But it definitely seems useful to understand that P(A and B) "defines a space or a model" and therefore I can assume symmetry.